# Php ООП: доступ из вложенного объекта к свойству объекта - контейнера

Tags: ооп, php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть 2 класса:

```
class parent_item extends item {
   public $daughters=array(); 
   public $cnt=0;
    function __construct($param) 
    {
        parent::__construct($param);
    }   
    function add_daugter($param) 
    {
        $daughter=new daughter_item($param) ;       
        array_push($this->daughters,$daughter);
    }
}

class daughter_item extends item {

    function __construct($param) 
    {
        parent::__construct($param);
    }

}
```

Получается, что в объекте класса parent_item одно из свойств - массив объектов класса daughter_item.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли из конструктора класса daughter_item получить значение свойства $cnt объекта класса parent_item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эти объекты братья а не родитель/потомок. родительский класс там item. Если хотите рассказать инициализированному из объекта другому объекту объекту о самом себе делайте так:

```
class parent_item extends item {
   public $daughters=array(); 
   public $cnt=0;
    function __construct($param) 
    {
        parent::__construct($param);
    }   
    function add_daugter($param) 
    {
        $daughter=new daughter_item($param,$this) ;  //расскажем о себе      
        array_push($this->daughters,$daughter);
    }
}

class daughter_item extends item {

    private $caller;

    function __construct($param,$caller) 
    {
        parent::__construct($param);
        $this->caller=$caller; //вызвавший объект
    }

}
```

только я бы переименовал объекты, т.к. это нарушает общепринятую терминологию (вот посмотрите `parent::__construct($param);` вызовет метод класса item а не объекта $parent;

назовите `class parent_item`  - `class ItemList` (кстати непонятно зачем его наследовать от `item` ?, он может быть тоже элементом какого-то списка?), `public $daughters` - `public $items`, `class daughter_item` - `class ItemInstance`, я вам гарантирую, это намного упростит вам и вашим объектам жизнь в будущем.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Наследую потому, что объекты обоих этих классов ведут себя во многом одинаково. А названия такие - чтобы было понятнее то, какие данные содержит объект. Задача такая, что нужно написать сложный довольно-таки алгоритм вывода элементов списка с одним уровнем вложенности и я подумала, что понятнее будет, если класс, соответствующий данным элементов верхнего уровня этого списка назвать parent, а вложенным - daugters.

Comment: кстати есть ещё вариант через синглтон сделать, чтобы был экземпляр класса item который все знает о своих потомках :)

Answer (score 0):

предайте указатель на объект `$this` при создании нового `daughter_item`

```
class parent_item extends item {
    …
    public function add_daugter($param) 
    {
        $this->daughters[] = new daughter_item($param, $this);
    }   
}

class daughter_item extends item {

    private $storage;

    public function __construct($param, $storage) 
    {
        parent::__construct($param);
        $this->storage = $storage;
    }

}
```

по другому эти классы ни как не сязаны между собой